# How to achieve return of one value with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

[image: View sheet]

What I'm trying to achieve: Return one value by multiple criteria (from 2 cells).
How: Intersection of particular row or column.

Based on picture, Row=Units Sold , Column=Years(2011,2012,2013,Total)

I tried using INDEX+MATCH because it sounded like what I'm looking for. But it doesn't allow multiple criteria, or at least I've tried and failed.
I've also tried IF+VLOOKUP, failed again.
All my effort would either return error N/A or #Value , etc.

Searched through this website but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm sure it's pretty simple, but I'm sort of a beginner at Excel. So, apologies if this question overlaps. And, HELP.

Comment: Use index() with one match() for the row and another match() for the column.

Comment: =INDEX(B2:F18,MATCH(H17,B2:B18,0),MATCH(I17,C2:F18,0)) -- I got error N/A

Comment: you match in one row and you should match in one column similarly.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

=INDEX(B2:F18,MATCH(H17,B2:B18,0),MATCH(I17,B2:F2,0))

Comment: Thank you! Now I've learned that I only needed to enter the first row for column_num. Which is why I've been getting errors.